# Inset map in print composer shifts when saved as pdf

Tags: qgis, print-composer

I'm working on a map in the print composer window of QGIS, with an inset map showing a larger extent and highlighting the area of my main map as an overview. Everything looks good in the print composer, but when I save as a pdf or image, or print as a pdf, the inset map stays the same in the print composer but the inset map on the pdf has totally shifted position and scale. I have the layers and styles for the map item locked.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: A screen shot might help.

Comment: Any chance you're using the OpenLayers plugin?

Comment: I do have the OpenLayers plugin installed